# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in UNIX

Tags: java, unix

When I run the UNIX .prog file, I got the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Session
    at APEmail.createMailSession(APEmail.java:231)
    at APEmail.main(Compiled Code)
Exception in thread "main"
```

It appears that the classpath is not set correctly:

```
...
SHLIB_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib
ORA_NLS33=$ORACLE_HOME/ocommon/nls/admin/data
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/usr/lib
cd $ORACLE_HOME/JRE/bin

**jre -classpath ../lib/rt.jar:$GENEX_TOP/java:$ORACLE_HOME/jlib/j2ee.jar:\
$ORACLE_HOME/jdbc/lib/classes111.zip APEmail "$login" "$ORACLE_SID" \
"$dname" "$fname" "$crname" "$vname" "$mail_server"**
...
```

So my question is what exactly am I missing here: correct classpath or else? Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the java mail classes http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-139225.html

Comment: Well, I sort of suspected about the java mail classes missing or replaced. Since I'm not a specialist, this is the first time with java, can anybody help me with java syntax of sort? The above script is in there to review. I would really appreciate, if someone to do that. Thanks in advance.